# Seelcting audio elements using classes and playing them

Tags: audio, jquery, playsound

I have sound clip registered in html:

```
<audio class="aaa" id="sss"><source src="url/sound.wav"/></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">var sss = document.getElementById("sss"); sss.volume='0.1';</script>
```

This sound can be played with mouseenter event on the certain div:

```
$('#divid').mouseenter(function () {
    $(sss.play());
});
```

How can this be achieved with audio class instead of id?

edit: solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.play()` is a method of the HTMLAudioElement object not the jQuery object, jQuery wrapper doesn't do anything here, as you are passing retuned value of the `.play()` method to it, you can select the element(s) using jQuery, gets DOM element object(s) from the collection and call the `.play()` method on it:

```
$('audio.aaa').get(0).play(); // works for the first matched element in the collection
```

If there are several elements, you can iterate through the collection using `.each()` method:

```
$('audio.aaa').each(function() {
   // `this` keyword here refers the HTMLAudioElements
   this.foo();
});
```

Comment: For some reason this work only in Firefox, not in Opera and Chrome.

Comment: @weaponx Each browser supports different audio format, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: my bad. the "issue" was up to caching. your code works smoothly on all 3 browsers. thanks for the help.